# Deserialize XML elements with different type name in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm stuck on how to solve the deserialization of this XML structure. The element "allocatables" have different types in the same namespace. It doesn't matter if these elements are deserialized in one or multiple lists in the "employeeAllocation" element/object.

This is the XML snippet.

```
    <ns3:EmployeeAllocationResponse
    xmlns:ns3="http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/"
    xmlns:ns2="http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/fault">
    <employeeAllocation>
        <allocatables
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Duty">
            <startTime>2020-11-03T14:09:00.000</startTime>
            <endTime>2020-11-03T22:50:00.000</endTime>
            <shortName>64280S</shortName>
        </allocatables>
        <allocatables
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Duty">
            <startTime>2020-11-03T14:09:00.000</startTime>
            <endTime>2020-11-03T22:50:00.000</endTime>
            <shortName>64280S</shortName>
        </allocatables>
    </employeeAllocation>
    <employeeAllocation>
        <allocatables
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Absence">
            <typeAbbreviation>STAG</typeAbbreviation>
            <typeLongname>STAG-dagar</typeLongname>
            <startTime>2020-11-03T00:00:00.000</startTime>
            <endTime>2020-11-04T00:00:00.000</endTime>
            <type>STAG</type>
        </allocatables>
    </employeeAllocation>
    <employeeAllocation>
        <allocatables
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Duty">
            <startTime>2020-11-03T21:00:00.000</startTime>
            <endTime>2020-11-04T06:45:00.000</endTime>
            <shortName>TPL1030</shortName>
            <rosterAbbreviation>DLT</rosterAbbreviation>
        </allocatables>
    </employeeAllocation>
</ns3:EmployeeAllocationResponse>
```

This is the "employeeAllocation" class

```
public class EmployeeAllocation
{
    [XmlElement("employee")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("allocatables")]
    public List<Alloctable> Alloctables { get; set; }
}
```

This is the "alloctables" class

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/", TypeName = "Duty")]
public class Alloctable
{
    [XmlElement("startTime", Namespace = "")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add a new type of "alloctables" type to my list of Alloctables. Now it can handle type="Duty" but crashed when trying to deserialize the other types.

Comment: What issue are you having with deserialization, what code are you using for it?

Comment: Ah sorry, will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by serializing some test data and getting it to compare with you input xml data.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeAllocationResponse));

            EmployeeAllocationResponse r = new EmployeeAllocationResponse()
            {
                Allocatables = new List<Allocatables>() {
                    new Duty(),
                    new Absence()
                }
            };
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME1, settings);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("ns2", "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/fault");
            ns.Add("ns3", "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/");
            ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, r, ns);

            EmployeeAllocationResponse response = (EmployeeAllocationResponse)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "EmployeeAllocationResponse", Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/")]
    public class EmployeeAllocationResponse
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "employeeAllocation", Namespace = "")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "allocatables", Namespace = "")]
        public List<Allocatables> Allocatables { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "allocatables", Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/")]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Duty)), XmlInclude(typeof(Absence))]
    public class Allocatables
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "startTime", Namespace = "")]
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "endTime", Namespace = "")]
        public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Duty", Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/")]
    public class Duty : Allocatables
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "shortName", Namespace = "")]
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "rosterAbbreviation", Namespace = "")]
        public string rosterAbbreviation { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Absence", Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/")]
    public class Absence : Allocatables
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "typeAbbreviation", Namespace = "")]
        public string typeAbbreviation { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "typeLongname", Namespace = "")]
        public string typeLongname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "type", Namespace = "")]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! The [IncludeXml] and [Root] was the key (pun intended ;D). Worked like a charm after adding these to the base class. Thank you jdweng!

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "allocatables", Namespace = "http://employeeallocation.intf.mb.ivu.de/")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DutyAlloctable))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AbsenceAlloctable))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DayOffAlloctable))]
public class AlloctableBase 
{

}
```