# Deserialize XML with different type rows C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Have a problem with deserialization XML. Can not understand how make property `data` different based on xml attribute `id`
xds generate one common property `data` that combine properties from data UserInfo + data UserTransactions

Tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901744/deserialize-xml-elements-with-different-type-name-in-c-sharp) thread but have no luck
Xml Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <data id="UserInfo">
    <rows>
      <row id="123" Name="Alex" phone="+1234567890"></row>
      <row id="321" Name="Sally" phone="+1234567890"></row>
    <rows>
  </data>
  <data id="UserTransactions">
    <rows>
      <row UserId="123" amount="100.1" date="2022-07-03"></row>
      <row UserId="123" amount="-100.1" date="2022-07-03"></row>
      <row UserId="321" amount="1" date="2022-07-03"></row>
    <rows>
  </data>
</document>
```

Question: Is it possible to deserialize to some class what will have properties based on xml attributes?
For example some like:

```cs
    public class document
    {
        // based on <data id='UserInfo'>
        public UserInfoRow[] dataUserInfos { get; set; }
        // based on <data id='UserTransaction'>
        public UserTransactionRow[] dataUserTransactions { get; set; }
    }
```

Code that i'm tried

```cs
namespace test
{
    public class document
    {
        [XmlElement("data")]
        public documentData[] data { get; set; }
    }
    public class documentData
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("rows")]
        [XmlArrayItem("row")]
        public row[] rows { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(UserInfoRow)), XmlInclude(typeof(UserTransactionRow))]
    public class row { }
    public class UserInfoRow : row
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserTransactionRow : row
    {
        [XmlAttribute("UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("amount")]
        public string amount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

No info from end classes

[image: Watch]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an inherited class with your xml.  Inherited classes requires a type attribute in the xml.  Instead you can use a custom IXmlSerialize like code below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test.document));
            test.document doc = (test.document)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
 

        }

    }
 
}
namespace test
{
    public class document
    {        
        [XmlElement("data")]
        public documentData[] data { get; set; }
    }
    public class documentData : IXmlSerializable
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        public List<UserInfoRow> userInfoRows { get; set; }
        public List<UserTransactionRow> userTransactionRows { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
 
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            id = reader.GetAttribute("id");       
            XmlSerializer serializer = null;
            XmlReader xmlChildReader = null; 
            switch (id)
            {
                case "UserInfo":
                    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfoRow)) ;
                    xmlChildReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                    while (xmlChildReader.ReadToFollowing("row"))
                    {     
                        UserInfoRow userRow = (UserInfoRow)serializer.Deserialize(xmlChildReader);
                        if (userInfoRows == null) userInfoRows = new List<UserInfoRow>();
                        userInfoRows.Add(userRow);
                    }
                    break;
                case "UserTransactions":
                    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserTransactionRow));
                    xmlChildReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                    while (xmlChildReader.ReadToFollowing("row"))
                    {
                        UserTransactionRow userRow = (UserTransactionRow)serializer.Deserialize(xmlChildReader);
                        if (userTransactionRows == null) userTransactionRows = new List<UserTransactionRow>();
                        userTransactionRows.Add(userRow);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            reader.ReadEndElement();

        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class UserInfoRow
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class UserTransactionRow
    {
        [XmlAttribute("UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("amount")]
        public string amount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is another solution that is more compact.  I eliminated the documentData class

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test.document));
            test.document doc = (test.document)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
 

        }

    }
 
}
namespace test
{
    public class document : IXmlSerializable
    {        
 
        public string id { get; set; }

        public List<UserInfoRow> userInfoRows { get; set; }
        public List<UserTransactionRow> userTransactionRows { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
 
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = null;
            XmlReader xmlChildReader = null;

            while (reader.ReadToFollowing("data"))
            {

                id = reader.GetAttribute("id");
                switch (id)
                {
                    case "UserInfo":
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInfoRow));
                        xmlChildReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                        while (xmlChildReader.ReadToFollowing("row"))
                        {
                            UserInfoRow userRow = (UserInfoRow)serializer.Deserialize(xmlChildReader);
                            if (userInfoRows == null) userInfoRows = new List<UserInfoRow>();
                            userInfoRows.Add(userRow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "UserTransactions":
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserTransactionRow));
                        xmlChildReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                        while (xmlChildReader.ReadToFollowing("row"))
                        {
                            UserTransactionRow userRow = (UserTransactionRow)serializer.Deserialize(xmlChildReader);
                            if (userTransactionRows == null) userTransactionRows = new List<UserTransactionRow>();
                            userTransactionRows.Add(userRow);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class UserInfoRow
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class UserTransactionRow
    {
        [XmlAttribute("UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("amount")]
        public string amount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `serializer = new ...` should be cached in a static field, otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `XmlInclude` expects an `xsi:type` attribute, which you don't have.

You can include it manually, by first deserializing into an `XDocument, modifying that, then deserializing your objects from that

```cs
 XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(document));  // always cache

 public static void Main()
 {
     var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<document>
<data id=""UserInfo"">
 <rows>
   <row id=""123"" Name=""Alex"" phone=""+1234567890""></row>
   <row id=""321"" Name=""Sally"" phone=""+1234567890""></row>
 </rows>
</data>
<data id=""UserTransactions"">
 <rows>
   <row UserId=""123"" amount=""100.1"" date=""2022-07-03""></row>
   <row UserId=""123"" amount=""-100.1"" date=""2022-07-03""></row>
   <row UserId=""321"" amount=""1"" date=""2022-07-03""></row>
 </rows>
</data>
</document>
";
     var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
     AddTypeDefinition(xdoc);
     Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
     var obj = (document)_serializer.Deserialize(xdoc.CreateReader());
     Console.WriteLine(obj.data[0].rows[0].GetType().Name);
 }
```

```cs
 private static void AddTypeDefinition(XDocument document)
 {
     // XNamespace always converts from string implicitly
     XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
     document.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi));
     foreach(var node in document.Root.Elements("data"))
     {
         string typeName;
         // decide based on "id" attribute
         if(node.Attribute("id").Value == "UserInfo")
             typeName = "UserInfoRow";
         else if(node.Attribute("id").Value == "UserInfo")
             typeName = "UserTransactionRow";
         else
             continue;

         foreach (var row in node.Element("rows").Elements("row"))
         {
             // xsi + "type" creates an XName with the namespace name
             // we have already added that declaration so becomes "xsi:type"
             row.Add(new XAttribute(xsi + "type", typeName));
         }
     }
 }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T340WT)

Comment: This solution is using XML Linq and not XML serialization.  XML Linq is more efficient than serialization.  I prefer XML Linq, but gave my answer using serialization like OP requested.

Comment: Not sure you read it correctly. I use `XmlSerializer` at the end to get it into a proper object model

Comment: Do you really think your solution is better than mine?  Your solution is a kludge to try to add the missing type attribute.   The best solutions are either to use just Xml Linq or use a custom serializer like my solution.

Comment: Arguable IMO. Is there something *wrong* with it that makes it not work? Your solution is kind of cleaner, but requires every part of `data` to be read manually (in this instance there is only `rows`). I also don't know how performance compares, YMMV. `XmlInclude` is the standard way to do this, so it's not inconceivable to fix up the XML to match. Now there are two answers, OP can choose.

Comment: We are basically doing the same things  You are enumerating each type and adding an attribute.  I'm enumerating and doing the deserialize.  So your solution have one extra step where you have to do the deserialize after enumerating and adding attribute.